# How to get the actual value of an angular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

For example I have an angular expression:

```
{{download.name}}
```

I want to get its actual value instead of its reference, which is "demo.txt". This element is generated like this. Its value changes with the scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="download in getDownloads()" />
```

When I write something like this, the value is correct.

```
<span class="input-group-addon" ng-model="name">{{openTokenPanel.name}}</span>
```

But if I try to use it in somewhere else, the output is wrong.(I get "Aria2 WebUI")

```
 modalScope.$download = function(){
              var filename = modalScope.name;
              console.log(filename);
          };
```

What should I do? 
For more information. See https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2
I am modifying this project. The last block of codes is added in "js/libs/angularui-bootstrap.js". The rests are added in "index.html"

The button is like this:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary"  id="download_now" ng-click="$download()">
 Download Now!
 </button>
```

I fixed this problem Thanks to DfKimera's suggestion:

> Find where in the HTML block inside ng-repeat the $download function is being >called (probably a download button with ng-click), modify it to include the >download variable, as such: ng-click="$download(download)"

In my case, I made some change to my code like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-primary"  id="download_now" ng-click="$download(download)">
 Download Now!
 </button>
```

JS code:

```
modalScope.$download = function(download){
              var filename = download.name;
              console.log(filename);
          };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want to do is modify the call to `$download()` so that the `download` object is passed. That way, accessing `download.name` will yield the corresponding variable.

There's no reliable way to do so by using the scope (`modalScope` object) alone, as it only references the last scope state, and not the internal state of `ng-repeat`

Comment: How should I do that? I added how I call this function at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Find where in the HTML block inside `ng-repeat` the `$download` function is being called (probably a download button with `ng-click`), modify it to include the `download` variable, as such: `ng-click="$download(download)"`.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed that problem.

Comment: Please accept this answer as the correct one, so in the future people can find and apply this. Thanks!

Comment: Edit the answer to include the solution. The comment is unreadable and not useful to other readers.

Comment: Done. Let me know if I did anything improper :-)